# msvsmon.exe not running on Windows IOT

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I installed the latest version of Windows IoT on a Raspberry Pi 3 and booted it up to deploy some Visual Basic code to it and I get an error that the Visual Studio Remote Debugger (msvsmon.exe) returns a null instead of an IP Address. Within the dashboard, there's a button to start the debugger, but it returns an error that the debugger must be copied over to the Pi before it can be started.

I can't deploy because it's not active and I can't start it because I haven't deployed anything yet.

How do I fix this catch 22?

Comment: Hi T. Cubbin, does the answer solve your issue? Feel free let me know if there is any concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue with a new flashed Windows IoT image. When I start the debugger via device portal the exact error message is:

> Failed to start the Visual Studio Remote Debugger. The Remote Debugger
>   needs to be copied to the device. This can be done by deploying an
>   application to the device using Visual Studio.

So you can reference "[Deploying an App with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appdeployment)" tutorial to see if it helps. It works for me.

- With the application open in Visual Studio, set the architecture in the toolbar dropdown. For Raspberry Pi 3, select ARM.
- Next, in the Visual Studio toolbar, click on the Local Machine dropdown and select Remote Machine.

After deploying from Visual Studio successfully, you will start the debugger from device portal successfully. **But no need to start debugger via device portal if you use visual studio debug/deploy.**

Comment: I tried all mentioned above, but I still have same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication